# PDO Bind params duplicate when looping

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I run the following code:

```
    $query = "select * from city where region = :region and country = :country";
    $stmt = db->prepare($query);
    $region = '06';
    $country = 'ad';
    $params = array(":region" => $region, ":country" => $country);
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindParam($key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

What i see in query log is :

```
 select * from city where region = 'ad' and country = 'ad'
```

Why is that? 
Note that it doesn't happen if I just bind parameters one after another like here:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':region', $region, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Because you're overwriting the statement, not adding to it. You could just `execute($params)`

Comment: @JayBlanchard, it worked for me, thanks!

Comment: IIRC bindParam binds by reference, not by value, so if you later change the variable value, the query automatically follows.

Answer (score 1):

In the `foreach()` statement you end up overwriting the bind, rather than adding to it. Since you have the array, you can just execute that:

```
$query = "select * from city where region = :region and country = :country";
$stmt = db->prepare($query);
$region = '06';
$country = 'ad';
$params = array(":region" => $region, ":country" => $country);
$stmt->execute($params); // put the array here
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Looks like the alternative to Jay's solution is:

`foreach ($params as $key => &$value) ....`